# Google Analytics conversions from one source/medium only

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

So I've installed Google Analytics and now I want to track conversions but I want the conversions code to only run if the user comes from an specific source/medium and ignore the rest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters and/or segments during the analysis to isolate the source that interests you.